Cartoon with moose, raccoon and cavemen
I don't remember much about it, but is was something I watched when I was little, and it's been bugging me that I can't find it! I was a kid during the early 2000's, but I don't recall if the cartoon was very old or not. I think the animation was claymation/stop-motion, but it may have been CG. I'm pretty sure it wasn't traditional, 2D animation. 
There's a moose that's playing catch with his friend, a raccoon. (or some small animal) The raccoon has a cold, and the moose catches it from playing with him. There's another segment (I think it was from the same cartoon...) where a caveman boy uses utensils to eat, and it freaks out his family, or they don't like it in some way. 
I'm pretty sure it wasn't a Rocky and Bullwinkle cartoon. 
I'm sorry I don't remember any more details!

Country\language? When were you little (how old would you say it was)? Can you describe the animation style?

Rocky and Bullwinkle?

Any search for a cartoon featuring a moose (and sidekick) has to start with Rocky and Bullwinkle...

I've added more detail. It was in English, and I'm pretty sure it wasn't a Rocky and Bullwinkle episode.

Gogs? 2d stop motion comedy show about cavemen circa 1994



http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0109915/

Don't know if you're still looking for an answer, seeing as how this is pretty old...but it's Morris the Moose, I was looking for the exact same thing!

Can you please elaborate on why it fits the description and\or perhaps add a synopsis or pictures?
